# I want to add a column content to another column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if it's possible to concatenate two columns in the second column by a query.

Example:

```
Reference | Description
ref1      | Des1 
ref2      | Des2 
ref3      | Des3
```

Result:

```
Reference | Description
ref1      | Des1 ref1 
ref2      | Des2 ref2 
ref3      | Des3 ref3
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `concat_ws()` does what you want:

```
select t.*, concat_ws(' ', reference, description)
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update` or computed column.